# Why haven't humans been able to make blood producing vats?

Tags: biotechnology, red-blood-cell, stem-cells

There are people in hospitals in life threatening circumstances that need blood packages, and they fully depend on blood donors' blood.
With our current technology, we have been able to "persuade" stem cells to differentiate into many kinds of cells or to replicate themselves, and even modified bacterial DNA to produce insulin. Why haven't we still made something that produces blood?

Comment: It's more difficult and expensive than expected. There are some prototype artificial blood, but they don't work as well as real blood. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_substitute One umbilical cord can provide 20 units of blood... but the research has hit a technical hitch. Search NEWS for artificial blood and blood pharming to find what has happened lately in the field.

Comment: Here is a history of artificial blood from 2019: https://www.popsci.com/artificial-blood-history-science/

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Please take the Tour to find out what the site is about and what questions are relevant. You will see that this is a question and answer site about specific biological problems, not a discussion site about why medical science has not advanced further.